# What does spill resistant keyboard mean exactly?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have searched a lot on this and can't find definitive information.

My laptop's specification says my keyboard is spill resistant, but can't find any other information what it actually means.

When we say "spill resistant",

- Is it almost the same as water proof?
- How does spill resistance work? I've read about having holes at the back of the laptop.
- What does spill-resistance really guarantee? How much is it protected from liquid damage? For example, if I put few droplets of water, wipe the keys using a kitchen wet wipe while cleanning, or any other kind of spill, does it protect from any of these?
- What about liquids with other contents (e.g. coffee, alcoholic and non-alcoholic wet wipes, juice, soap, etc.)

My laptop is Lenovo T460. Thanks

Comment: It probably means different things to different keyboard manufacturers. For instance, here is Toshiba: http://www.toshiba.pl/Contents/Toshiba_teg/EU/Others/EasyGuard/tech_insights/Tech-Insight-Spill-Resistant-Keyboard-EN.pdf. The spill resistance feature for them is just that it delays liquid reaching the mainboard, giving time to implement steps to treat it (shutdown, turn upside-down, etc).

Comment: For lenovo, it appears to mean that it has a drainage system that can disperse up to a certain volume of liquid to prevent it from causing damage: https://shop.lenovo.com/ISS_Static/WW/AG/merchandising/US/popups/promos/spillresistantkeyboard.html

Comment: "Spill resistant" is marketing language that does not have a regulated meaning.  It doesn't guarantee any kind of performance or safety factor, or specify any specific type of design, or mean almost waterproof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, none of the keyboards I used had any IP rating. So they are not water proof or at least not certified for water proof.

Spill-resistant keyboard usually has a polymer film that covers the critical component like circuit board, so the spilled liquid won't touch any of these and liquid will flow over the film. If you see the bottom of these keyboards, you will see some holes that has water drop or some marks near them. Your spilled liquid will flow out through these holes.

It is designed to be spill-resistance but not 'guaranteed'. Even if a IP68 water proof phone does not guarantee it. You will void the warranty if it is under liquid damage.

Answer (score -1):

The HP spill-resistant keyboard is designed using a thin layer of Mylar film under the keyboard.

**source**: HP ProBook 450 G0 Notebook PC Product Specifications | HP® Customer Support
https://support.hp.com/hk-en/document/c03783671#AbT1

Answer (score -2):

A spill-resistant keyboard usually has a protective film that covers the circuit board & prevents short cercuit.

Source - [Mechanical keybaord](https://www.quantumhitech.com/blog/gamers-and-mechanical-keyboards-why-the-two-are-inseparable)